# How to merge two dataframes by using a common column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes namely high_scores1 and high_scores2 like this:

```
match_id    inn1    batting_team    bowling_team    runs1
1              1    KKR                 RCB         222
2              1    CSK                 KXIP        240
3              1    RR                  DD          129
4              1    MI                  RCB         165


match_id    inn2    batting_team    bowling_team    runs2
    1         2     RCB              KKR            82
    2         2     KXIP             CSK            207
    3         2     DD               RR             132
    4         2     RCB              MI             166
```

Now i need to merge these two using the column match_id such that the new dataframe looks something like this:

```
match_id  inn   batting_team    bowling_team    runs1   inn2  runs2
1          1    KKR                 RCB         222     2     82
2          1    CSK                 KXIP        240     2     207
3          1    RR                  DD          129     2     132
4          1    MI                  RCB         165     2     166
```

I tried the following code:

```
high_scores1[['match_id','inn1','batting_team','bowling_team','runs1']].merge(high_scores2, left_on = 'match_id', right_on = 'match_id', how = 'left')
```

But it did not work. How do i merge the dataframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just merge on a subset of the second DataFrame's columns with

```
high_scores1.merge(high_scores2[['match_id','inn2', 'runs2']], on='match_id')
```

**Demo**

```
>>> high_scores1.merge(high_scores2[['match_id','inn2', 'runs2']], on='match_id')
  batting_team bowling_team  inn1  match_id  runs1  inn2  runs2
0          KKR          RCB     1         1    222     2     82
1          CSK         KXIP     1         2    240     2    207
2           RR           DD     1         3    129     2    132
3           MI          RCB     1         4    165     2    166
```

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
scores = high_scores1.merge(high_scores2[['match_id', 'inn2', 'runs2']], on = 'match_id')
```